# Getting DevExpress Chart Series Values From Array VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, charts, devexpress

I was trying to set DevExpress Chart Series from Data inside SQL Table.
Everything went fine except that the chart takes only the last attribute from the last series.
My code is:

```
con.Open() 'it opens SQL Connection
For i = 0 To (CheckedListBoxControl1.CheckedItems.Count - 1) 'list from ListBox        
    Lst.Add(CheckedListBoxControl1.CheckedItems(i).ToString) 'Putting Data in Array List
    Dim Strl As String = String.Format("Select * from VPRogressCumulative where fname like '{0}' and lname like  '{1}' order by id, no, CAST('1.' + date AS datetime)", ComboBox1.Text, Lst(i))

    Dim sqlCom As New SqlCommand(Strl)
    sqlCom.Connection = con
    Dim myDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom)
    Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
    myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "VPRogressCumulative")
    ChartControl1.DataSource = myDataSet
    ChartControl1.DataAdapter = myDA

    Dim ser As New Series(Lst(i), ViewType.Line)
    ChartControl1.Series.Add(ser)

    ser.ArgumentDataMember = "VPRogressCumulative.Date"
    ser.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(New String() {"VPRogressCumulative.Cumulative"})
Next
con.Close()
```

I believe my Problem is in:

```
Dim ser As New Series(Lst(i), ViewType.Line)
ChartControl1.Series.Add(ser)
ser.ArgumentDataMember = "VPRogressCumulative.Date"
ser.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(New String() {"VPRogressCumulative.Cumulative"})
```

Last two lines are giving the same series new attributes which I wasn't able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
ChartControl1.DataSource = myDataSet
ChartControl1.DataAdapter = myDA
```

In each iteration of cycle you are creating the new `DataSet` and it's overrides previous `DataSource` in your `ChartControl1`. Your must use `Series.DataSource` instead of `ChartControl.DataSource`. Also you can use `DataTable` instead of `DataSet`.
Here is example:

```
'Your code:
'Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
'myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "VPRogressCumulative")
'ChartControl1.DataSource = myDataSet
'ChartControl1.DataAdapter = myDA

'Replace with this:
Dim myDataTable As DataTable = New DataTable("VPRogressCumulative")
myDA.Fill(myDataTable)

Dim ser As New Series(Lst(i), ViewType.Line)
ChartControl1.Series.Add(ser)

'Your code.
'ser.ArgumentDataMember = "VPRogressCumulative.Date"
'ser.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(New String() {"VPRogressCumulative.Cumulative"})

'Replace with this:
ser.DataSource = myDataTable
ser.ArgumentDataMember = "Date"
ser.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(New String() {"Cumulative"})
```